# The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to JSONArray

Tags: java, json, servlets

I am getting an JSON object then converting it into array and trying to access the properties or values, but getting error as `The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to JSONArray`

I have to save the JSON data into my Database thats why I am getting all to values in array

**My code**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(request.getInputStream());
    String imageData = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println(imageData);
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(imageData);
    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("ImageData");

    JSONObject innerObj = new JSONObject(jsonArray[0]); // this one is throwing error 
    // eror is `The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to JSONArray`
    String counter = innerObj.getString("Counter");
    String name = innerObj.getString("Name");
    String isActive = innerObj.getString("IsActive");     
    System.out.println(counter);

}

System.out.println(imageData); it prints -->
```

`{"ImageData":[{"Counter":"Counter A","Name":"CountA1.jpg","IsActive":"Y"},{"Counter":"Counter A","Name":"CountA2.jpg","IsActive":"Y"}]}`

System.out.println(jsonArray); This one prints -->

`[{"Counter":"Counter A","IsActive":"Y","Name":"CountA1.jpg"},{"Counter":"Counter A","IsActive":"Y","Name":"CountA2.jpg"}]`

I have commented the line in my code where I am getting error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [getJSONObject](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#getJSONObject(int)) method

```
JSONObject innerObj =  jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
```

> Returns the value at index if it exists and is a JSONObject.

Comment: This worked but `String counter = innerObj.getString("Counter");` only gives counter A I want all Counter A,Counter B, and C all are dynamic

Comment: @viveksingh You can loop through jsonArray

Comment: I Ma doing it `for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
  {
   JSONObject innerObj =  jsonArray.getJSONObject(0); // this one is throwing error 
         // eror is `The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to JSONArray`
   String counter = innerObj.getString("Counter");
   String name = innerObj.getString("Name");
   String isActive = innerObj.getString("IsActive");  
   System.out.println(counter);
  }` but stil getting two times `Counter A`

Comment: each time it is printing counter A here 3 times Counter A

Comment: @viveksingh inside a loop you need to change `0` to `i`: `JSONObject innerObj = 
 jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);`

Comment: But for Which length I have to loop it because here Counters are 3 then names are 4 and IsActive are also 4, it is looping only 3 times

Answer (score 0):

You can't add square brackets to JSONArray like jsonArray[0], You have to use jsonArray.getJSONObject("index");